# componentWillReceiveProps in React Native vs ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am in the process transferring my React Webapp to a React Native version.

In React Native, I have this in the login page. I am using react-navigation.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const { requestStatus, currentUser } = nextProps
    const getUserInProgress = get(requestStatus, GET_MY_DETAILS, true)

    if (!getUserInProgress) {
      if (currentUser) {
        currentUser.verified_mobile ? this.props.navigation.navigate('Dashboard') : this.props.navigation.navigate('VerifyMobile')
      } else if (!currentUser) {
        console.log('not logged in')
      }
    }
  }
```

So on the login page, it gets the user details and check if mobile is verified and then if it isn't, goes to verify mobile page.

On the verify mobile page, when a call is made, this componentWillReceiveProps on the login page still runs even though it's not the current active page.

I have the same logic/code in ReactJS and it behaves totally different.

Is this normal for React Native?

Edit:

Let me clarify what my problem is.

When I am not on the login page and I am on the verify mobile page. The componentWillReceiveProps is still running despite that page is in the history. This did not happen when I built the reactjs app. It is only happening in the react native app. So I'm wondering if this is normal behavior for pages in the history stack to run its componentWillReceiveProps?

Comment: could you please elaborate on what behavior do you experience and what exactly the error?

Comment: Well yes, its still in the stack, so it still exists. It just not shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function still executes in react-native because it is still active in the stack while in react app, only the displayed page is active so functions in other pages are 'disabled' in a sense.